# I want some help on how to use the Mark down feature within Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

There is a built in feature within visual studio code which allows one to use markdown anywhere within visual studio code.  I hope someone can help in helping me understand how to use this feature and get it working ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan of "quoting documentation." In this case, I think the folks at VS Code deserve some credit.  They do a really good job of explaining how to use custom "markdown style sheets ."

From the docs:

> You can also use your [own CSS in the Markdown preview](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown#_using-your-own-css) with the
>   `"markdown.styles": []` [setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings). This lists URLs for style sheets to
>   load in the Markdown preview. These stylesheets can either be https
>   urls, or relative paths to local files in the current workspace.
>
> For example, to load a stylesheet called Style.css at the root of your
>   current workspace, use File > Preferences > Settings to bring up the
>   workspace settings.json file and make this update:
>
> ```
> // Place your settings in this file to overwrite default and user settings.
> {
>     "markdown.styles": [
>         "Style.css"
>     ]
> }
> ```

Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

-rob

Comment: >"markdown.styles": [
        "H:\\Sync\\Custom Program Settings\\vscode_settingsuivscode.css" This is what I have within my `usersettings.json` file; but how does the style sheet know what markdown tags to style ? How do you write the CSS file, for example; `#` means a `H1` header how would you style this ?

Comment: Markdown language features is the extension I'm using. I was informed I have to place the `styles.css` file within the project file, then again I was also informed it doesn't work; maybe this can help in understanding and getting this extension to work ?

Comment: I was able to modify the default style in VS Code.  I will update my answer to explain further.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use that file "https://github.com/SepCode/vscode-markdown-style/blob/master/preview/github.css", we know that "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SepCode/vscode-markdown-style/master/preview/github.css", the URL is not working.

I have a good idea, we can use Github Pages.

Add a submodule in your repository, like this "`git submodule add https://github.com/SepCode/vscode-markdown-style.git`". And now we can use the URL "https://sepcode.github.io/vscode-markdown-style/preview/github.css" set markdown.styles.

Step:

- clone your GitHub pages "`git clone https://github.com/SepCode/SepCode.github.io.git`"
- `cd SepCode.github.io`
- `git submodule add https://github.com/SepCode/vscode-markdown-style.git`
- `git commit -am 'added vscode-markdown-style module'`
- `git push`
- setting vscode setting.json

  ```
  {
      "markdown.styles":["https://sepcode.github.io/vscode-markdown-style/preview/github.css"]
  }
  ```

the vscode-markdown-style repository is just an example, we should use ourself's CSS file. This way is more convenient and controllable.

Comment: I must use a cloned repository to get vscode to read a style sheet which customizes the look of markdown tags; I can't have it stored on the local machine ?

Comment: @Christopher you can see vscode github issue.  We now restrict the markdown preview to only loading resources inside the current workspace for security reasons. Workaround is to move the css file into your workspace or publish the css as a markdown extension extension

Comment: Sorry, what vscode github issue ? Do you mean I have to place the *markdown* style sheet inside the workspace; what was different about it before, one could place it anywhere ? What do you mean publish the css as a markdown extension ?

Comment: What was @RobV8R talking about ?